# Does 1 Corinthians 11:20; 14:23 suggest the Corinthians had their own room for worship?

Tags: greek, word-study, 1-corinthians, worship

Here are the verses in question (NKJV, bold emphasis mine):

> Therefore when you come together **in one place**, it is not to eat the Lord’s Supper. (1 Corinthians 11:20)

> Therefore if the whole church comes together **in one place**, and all speak with tongues, and there come in those who are uninformed or unbelievers, will they not say that you are out of your mind? (1 Corinthians 14:23)

I have two questions:

1. Does the phrase which the New King James Version translates "in one place" (**επὶ το αυτο**) reference a "place," or can it simply refer to being "together" without referencing a specific "place"? (See NASB and ESV, which simply translate the phrase "together.")
2. If the phrase translated "in one place" (**επὶ το αυτο**) does, in fact, reference a "place," does this suggest that the Corinthians had a room or building separate from their houses to meet in?

Answer (score 2):

ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτό literally means "on the same"

Note where the phrase is also used

> But when the Pharisees had heard that he had put the Sadducees to silence, they were gathered **together** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτό⸃].
> (Matt. 22:34, KJV)

> Two women shall be grinding **together** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτό]; the one shall be taken, and the other left.
> (Luke 17:35, KJV)

> And in those days Peter stood up in the midst of the disciples, and said, (the number of names **together** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτὸ] were about an hundred and twenty,)
> (Acts 1:15, KJV)

> And when the day of Pentecost was fully come, they were all with one accord in **one place** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτό].
> (Acts 2:1, KJV)

> And all that believed were **together** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτὸ], and had all things common;...
> (Acts 2:44, KJV)

> The kings of the earth stood up, and the rulers were gathered **together** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτὸ] against the Lord, and against his Christ.
> (Acts 4:26, KJV)

> Defraud ye not one the other, except it be with consent for a time, that ye may give yourselves to fasting and prayer; and come **together** [ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτὸ] again, that Satan tempt you not for your incontinency.
> (1 Cor. 7:5, KJV)

Thus, it is unlikely that ἐπὶ τὸ αὐτό means any more than together.

> Although gathered in the same place, the Corinthians no longer partook of a common meal expressing their union with one another in the Lord, but each group ate apart.
> --
> Brown, R. E., Fitzmyer, J. A., & Murphy, R. E. (1996). The Jerome Biblical commentary (Vol. 2, p. 270). Prentice-Hall.

Comment: Very helpful, effective response, +1

Comment: Very good response. +1.